# Convolution Theorem in 2D

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, convolution

I'm trying to verify the convolution theorem for a 2D problem via MATLAB: Convolution with a filter in spacial domain is equivalent to multiplying with the filter in frequency domain. I wrote the following code. After step 2, I get a blurred image expected. But after step 3, I don't get the same blurred image as expected, the output figure of the is code is shown below. What is wrong in my assumptions ?

```
% 1- Read image and create a domain frequqncy window
im = imread('High_Detail.jpg');
im = imresize(im,[100,100]);
im = rgb2gray(im);
im = im2double(im);
window_fft_shifted = zeros([100,100]);
window_fft_shifted(50-11:50+11,50-11:50+11) = 1;

% 2- FFT then Multiplying it by window then get IFFT, a blurred image expected
im_fft = fft2(im);
im_fft_shifted = fftshift(im_fft);
im_fft_shifted_W = im_fft_shifted .* window_fft_shifted;
im_result_1 = ifft2(ifftshift(im_fft_shifted_W));

% 3- Get IFFT of window, convolve im with it, the same blurred image is expected
window = ifft2(ifftshift(window_fft_shifted));
im_result_2 = conv2(im, window);

% 4- Plot
figure;
subplot(2,2,1); imshow(im);
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(im_result_1);
subplot(2,2,4); imshow(im_result_2);
```

[image]

Comment: You need to pad, otherwise you're doing circular convolution.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks, but which signal should I pad ?

Comment: You need to zero pad both images to at least (w1 + w2 - 1), (h1 + h2 - 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line :

```
window = ifft2(ifftshift(window_fft_shifted));
```

should include ifftshift to compensate the MATLAB anti-symmetric signal representation:

```
window = ifftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(window_fft_shifted)));
```